# SQL Function with variadic varchar input and variadic integer output

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I know I could do the following with a inner join and a select with a correspondence table, but would rather have a function.

Let's says I have a query such as `select * from foobar where is_valid in ('yes', 'no')`. Unfortunately foobar.is_valid is an integer, 0 or 1 only.

I'ld like to create a function that maps the varchar to integers, something like `select * from foobar where is_valid in fn_yesno_to_int('yes', 'no')`. Is this even possible?

I'm not at liberty to change the `in` clause to something else, nor am I at liberty to call the function for each value in the `in` clause (no `in (func('yes'), func('no'))`).

My last resort would be to create a correspondence table such as {{0, 'no'}, {1, 'yes'}} and use it and drop the idea of using a function. Another, probably better, option would be to flip the issue around and call the function on `foobar.is_valid` mapping the 0,1 to no,yes; but I'm very curious to know if the function taking an array and returning an array in my case is even possible.

Comment: No trivially.  You can do this using arrays, but it seems like a lot of work for something that can be done pretty trivially using other methods.

Comment: can you change the `in (` to `= any (`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. Which is alexey-bashtanov 's second solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to write a function that makes the syntax `where is_valid in fn_yesno_to_int('yes', 'no')` valid.

However, you can write a function that can be used like `where is_valid in (select * from fnyn1('yes', 'no'))` or like `where is_valid = any(fnyn2('yes', 'no'))`:

```
CREATE function fnyn1(variadic labels text[] default '{}') returns setof int as $$
    select column1
    from (values(0, 'no'),(1, 'yes'))_
    join unnest(labels) u on column2 = u;
$$ language sql;

CREATE function fnyn2(variadic labels text[] default '{}') returns int[] as $$
    select array(
        select column1
        from (values(0, 'no'),(1, 'yes'))_
        join unnest(labels) u on column2 = u
    );
$$ language sql;
```